# Why are square brackets needed to stringify all elements of a Map in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, brackets, stringify

Problem:
I can't seem to find a satisfactory explanation of why javascript Maps need square brackets for the JSON.stringify method to "reach"(?) into the nested elements. I think I'm missing something about ES6, or something inherent to the Map data type.

I can convert the Map to an object, and stringify- but why is this extra step necessary?

My experiment:

```
const blah = new Map();

blah.set('u', {
    'something': [{'hey':98}, 56, 'bob']
});

blah.set({
    'hey': {'hey': 78}
}, 'what?');

console.log(JSON.stringify(...blah));

//["u",{}]
//I thought this would yield the result of the below console.log

console.log(JSON.stringify([...blah]))

//[["u",{"something":[{"hey":98},56,"bob"]}],[{"hey":{"hey":78}},"what?"]]
//Why are the square brackets needed to stringify and display each element of 
//the map?
```

This [article](https://macwright.org/2017/03/13/maps-not-strictly-better.html#con-maps-and-json-dont-get-along) confirms the behavior, but doesn't explain why it happens.

Comment: What that syntax does is create an array from the map.

Comment: Map objects are mostly (probably always) stringified like `JSON.stringify([...myMap])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(...blah)` is [argument spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which takes the values you get when iterating over the map:

- `['u', {'something': …}]`
- `[{'hey': …}, 'what?']`

and passes them as distinct arguments to `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(
    ['u', {'something': …}],
    [{'hey': …}, 'what?']
);
```

The second argument to `JSON.stringify` [is supposed to be a replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Since you’ve given it something that isn’t a function, it ignores that.

Argument spread is not remotely what you want. What you want is to convert the map to an array of key/value pairs, and that’s what `[...blah]` does. `Array.from(blah)` would have the same effect.